# Woocommerce set customer provided note also return html tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making some changes to customer provided note and order note for client. Here is my code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'dvs_add_tm_data_order_note' );
function dvs_add_tm_data_order_note($order_id) {
    $options = THEMECOMPLETE_EPO_API()->get_option( $order_id ,'all' );
    foreach ($options as $item_id => $epos){
        $item = new WC_Order_Item_Product($item_id);
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $output .= "<br><strong>{$product->get_name()}</strong><br>";
        foreach ($epos as $epo){
            $output .= '<i> -- '. $epo['name'] .' : </i>'. $epo['value'] . "<br>";  
        }
    }
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $output .= "<br><strong>Customer Details</strong><br>";
    $output .= "Name: {$order->get_billing_first_name()}<br>";
    $output .= "Phone: <a href='tel:92{$order->get_billing_phone()}'>{$order->get_billing_phone()}</a><br>";
    $output .= "Address: {$order->get_billing_address_1()}<br>";
    $output .= "City: {$order->get_billing_city()}<br>";
    $output .= "Total: {$order->get_formatted_order_total()}<br>";
    $output .= "Payment: {$order->get_payment_method_title()}<br>";
    $order->add_order_note( $output );
    $order->set_customer_note( $output );
    $order->save();
}
```

The output is working perfect on order_note
[image]

but it in customer provided note it also returns html tags
[image]

How to fix this ?
Regards

Comment: Can you please provide hook or better explanation where you echo (print) this HTML? I know the reason but want to explain better with code you have to display message.

Comment: Sir the thing is html tags working in order->note but not working in customer->note

Comment: Did you try using `$order->get_customer_note();`? Update your question and show us print code.

Answer (score 0):

Since Woocommerce 3 you can't access anymore properties From the `WC_Order` object. You need to use the `WC_Order` method `get_customer_note()`:

```
// Get the note
$customer_note = $order->get_customer_note();
// decode entity to regular HTML
$customer_note = html_entity_decode($customer_note);
// Print somwhere
echo $customer_note;
```

Your problem is encoded HTML code to the HTML entities and you must decode it to regular HTML using PHP function [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and print decoded string.

I hope this will help you to understand your problem.